# Existence of a boundary point

Tags: general-topology

I am not particularly well-versed in topology, so I wanted to check with you whether there exists a much simpler argument to prove the following statement or whether there are problems with my proof. The statement also seems to be a very standard result but I could not find a reference in e.g. a book on basic topology (references would also be appreciated). The statement is as follows:

Consider $\mathbb{R}^d$ with its usual topology where $d \geq 1$. Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be bounded. Then, for any $x\in A$ and $y\in A^c$, there exists a point in the line segment joining $x$ and $y$ ($x$ and $y$ included) that also belongs to the boundary $\partial A$ of $A$.

My argument goes like this: Consider a bijection $T$ from $[0,1]$ to such a line segment so that $T(0) = x$ and $T(1) = y$ (Actually this step is not very necessary but makes the argument a little more visual). For any $a\in[0,1]$, let $f(a) = 0$ if $T(a) \in A$ and otherwise let $f(a) = 1$ if $T(a) \notin A$ so that $f(0) = 0$ (because $x$ is a member of $A$ and $T(0) = x$) and $f(1) = 1$. It is now sufficient to find some $b\in[0,1]$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $f((b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)\cap[0,1]) = \{0,1\}$. "Topologically," this would mean that every open neighborhood of $b$ contains points from both $A$ and $A^c$, which would mean $b\in\partial A$.

We can find such a $b$ constructively as follows: Let $I_0 = [0,1]$ (We will have a recursion $I_1,I_2,\ldots,$ which will all be intervals). Recall $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. Consider $f(\frac{1}{2})$. If $f(\frac{1}{2}) = 0$, we set $I_1 = [\frac{1}{2},1]$, otherwise if $f(\frac{1}{2}) = 1$ we set $I_1 = [0,\frac{1}{2}]$. In either case, $f$ takes the values $0$ and $1$, respectively at the lower and upper end points of $I_1$. We continue this process by dividing $I_1$ on its middle, and so on, while at each iteration we make sure that $f(\min I_n) = 0$ and $f(\max I_n) = 1$. Let $b = \lim \min I_n  =\lim \max I_n$ (It is not difficult to see the limits exist) and we are done.

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that interval [0,1] is connected. Get a contradiction assuming that such boundary point does not exist.

Comment: I would just choose $b = \sup\{z \in [0,1] : T(z) = 0\}$.

Comment: @andybenji Hahaha, you are right. No need for my last paragraph.

Comment: Your proof is fine, its just allows a few shortcuts, as the answers and other comments show

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for the verification. Indeed there were a lot of shortcuts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my stab at it.

Write $X=\mathbb R^n$. You can write $X= \operatorname{int} A\cup \operatorname{ext} A\cup\partial A$, and these three sets are mutually disjoint. We may assume $x\in \operatorname{int} A$ and $y\in\operatorname{ext} A$, since otherwise we have the desired point. The obvious linear map $f:I\rightarrow X$ of the unit interval onto $[x,y]$ is continuous, and meets both $\operatorname{int} A$ and $\operatorname{ext} A$ by construction. The image is connected by continuity, so it cannot be contained in $\operatorname{int} A \cup\operatorname{ext} A$ since otherwise we would have a disconnection of the image. Therefore, $f(I) \cap\partial A\neq\varnothing$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks, this looks much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you. This works for any space where the path from $x$ to $y$ exists as a continuous function. I don't think boundedness is required in your case, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Define the function d that gives you the distance o f a point in $\mathbb R^d$ to the boundary of A , so that d is negative in the interior and positive in the exterior. Show d is continuous.Then restrict d to the line segment L joining x,y, so that d takes on both positive and negative values. Then, by the IVTheorem, d must take the value 0 at some z in L , so that z is in both L and in the boundary of A.

Comment: Thanks, this also looks pretty cool.

Comment: Thanks; I enjoy this type of problems.